# GitPython equivalent of git update-ref?

Tags: gitpython

I would like to create a new reference that is not a tag nor a branch, in the same way `git update-ref` would:

```
git update-ref refs/pull/201/head ac8d616ea3598e49935908e5685e72038a37cd8f
```

How can I do that with GitPython ? I found [TagReference.create](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=tagreference#git.refs.tag.TagReference.create) to create a tag and I probably need a similar.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to tags or branch creation, there is no GitPython wrapper. Instead the `git update-ref` should be used via the [GitCmd](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference.html#module-git.cmd) generic wrapper like so:

```
import git
r = git.Repo('.')
r.git.update_ref('foobar', '8d5f33071777bb59bb45adae178fa1fb69101e68')
```